# update statement for large Transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-update, sql-server-2014

I am new to this site and I am really stuck on performing a large update for a database . I was giving a list of Transactions that needs to be updated. here is a small example of the database along with the desired output at the end

The Ask is. I have a list of transactions IDs that the purchaseID points to a PurchaseTypeID =2 and would like all the Transactions to point to a purchaseID that has the PruchaseTypeID of 5 instead based on each customer .Example. Transaction ID 1 has the source Purchase ID 1987 which if you look for that id in the purchase table. It has the amount of $780 and customer ID of 1 . this Transaction was closed by mistake to a destination PurchaseID 32875 (every customer has a fake purchase destination that carries the PurchaseTypeID of 2 and 5 in the Purchase Table along with True purchases which can be picked out by the IsPurchase Column). Now I wanted to update that transaction to point to Purchase ID 6000 which again carries the PurchaseTypeID of 5. which contains the purchase type id of 5. To sum up. the Ask again is grab all the transactions that have a puchaseID destination that points to a PurchaseTypeID of 2 and have it pointing to the newpurchaseID destination that carries the purchaseTypeId of 5. 
[My Database Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIT4C.jpg)

Comment: When you say Transaction, are you referring to the MSSQL Keyword for TRANSACTION, or some business definition of "transaciton"?

Comment: My Table [Transaction] and not the MSSQL keyword function.

Comment: I think its still not quite clear to me how transactionID 1 ends up at 6000 when it starts with 32875. Can you explain the connections a bit more if the answers have not yet been helpful?

Comment: I have updated my question since my comment was too long to fit into the comment section. Please see the question again.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE <<Your table name>>
  SET PurchaseTypeID = 5
WHERE PurchaseTypeID = 2
```

Or if you want to update this for certain customers you could have:

```
UPDATE <<Your table name>>
  SET PurchaseTypeID = 5
 WHERE PurchaseTypeId = 2
  AND CustomerID = <<desired customer id>>
```

Or are you running into performance issues?

Comment: That was not my ask. Please take a look at my tables carefully. customers have purchases. some are not true purchases but are destinations with purchasetypeID. PurchasesID are then linked to transactions as a source and destination. I need to update the destinations with purchaseIDs that carries the PurchaseTypeID of 5 for each customer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update p
set p.purchasetypeid = 2 
from purchases p
join transactions t 
on t.PurchaseId = p.PurchaseId
where t.transactionId in (YOUR_ID_LIST)
```

Editing based on comments below, I'm not sure that's the best approach, but here we go:

```
-- Create a temporary table for the records you wanna update, as you can check first and update later
select t.Id, 
(select top 1 p1.purchaseId from Purchases p1 where p1.customerId = p.customerId and p1.PurchaseTypeId = 5) as newPurchaseId
into ##temp_PurchaseTransactions
from Transactions t
join Purchases p
on p.Id = t.PurchaseId;
```

-- Actually update the Transactions
update t
set t.PurchaseIdForwardedTo = newPurchaseId
from Transactions t
join ##temp_PurchaseTransactions t1
on t1.id = t.id

Comment: Tavares . I need to update the Transaction table.specifically the transaction.purchaseforwardedTo column. See my Desired updated output screen shot attached in my question please.

Comment: That's a bit tricky, how do you know which PurchaseId is the correct one for that other PurchaseId? Couldn't there be more of one PurchaseId with TypeId = 5 for the same customer?

Comment: There would be only purchaseID with the purchaseTypeID of 5 for each customer. so Transactions with True Purchase Ids will always point to that destination for each customer as shown in my output result.